# How to load a text file on a ram in VHDL?

Tags: text, vhdl, rgb, ram

i have a text file describing an image in terms of it's RGB components i want to load that file on the FPGA to produce a RGB signal so if you would be kind enough to enlighten me i would be thankful

Okey so this is what i came up with but there's a problem the synthesis is taking forever to finish, so what do you think is the problem here ??!

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use STD.TEXTIO.ALL; 

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity RGB_Gen is

  port(CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
       EN : in STD_LOGIC;
         R,G,B : out STD_LOGIC);

end RGB_Gen;

architecture Behavioral of RGB_Gen is

  Type ram is array (0 to 611) of BIT_VECTOR(203 downto 0);

  impure function InitRamFromFile(Filename : in string) return ram is

   File readFile : text is in Filename;
   Variable lineRead : Line;
    Variable my_ram : ram;

    begin

      for i in ram'range loop
         readline(readFile, lineRead);
         read(lineRead, my_ram(i));
     end loop;

     return my_ram;

  end function;

  function toSTD(B : in Bit) return STD_LOGIC is
  begin    
        if B = '1' then 
           return '1';
        else 
           return '0';
      end if;
  end function;

  Signal my_ram : ram := InitRamFromFile("C:\Users\Mos_X\Desktop\output.txt");

  begin

    process(CLK)

     Variable X : Integer := 0;
     Variable Y : Integer := 0;

     begin

     if rising_edge(CLK) then
       if EN = '0' then 
          R <= '0';
            G <= '0';
            B <= '0';
        else 
           R <= toSTD((my_ram(Y)(X)));
            G <= toSTD((my_ram(Y + 204)(X)));
            G <= toSTD((my_ram(Y + 408)(X)));       
        end if;

       if X = 203 then 
           X := 0;
         if Y = 203 then 
            Y := 0;
         else
            Y := Y + 1;
           end if;
        else 
           X := X + 1;
        end if;

    end if;

 end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: If synthesis is slow you've asked it do do something tough, a three port RAM (ROM) with 204 bit wide ports. You have a process containing three 204 bit to 1 bit multiplexers. Consider three RAMs (ROMs) 1 bit wide or wasting a bit of memory and use something 4 bits wide.

Comment: is there's a way to convert line read to STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ?? i think what i am doing there using read(lineRead, my_ram(i)) is incorrect. the synthesis issue isn't much of a problem for me now, my priority is to get it to work.

Comment: You are assigning `G` two times when reading from the RAM. Is this intended? And which synthesis tool are you using?

Answer (score 1):

so the problem is the two counters in the  code were incrementing even when the Enable signal was 0 that was causes the static so this

```
 if rising_edge(CLK) then
       if EN = '0' then 
          R <= '0';
            G <= '0';
            B <= '0';
        else 
           R <= toSTD((my_ram(Y)(X)));
            G <= toSTD((my_ram(Y + 204)(X)));
            G <= toSTD((my_ram(Y + 408)(X)));   

           if X = 203 then 
              X := 0;
            if Y = 203 then 
               Y := 0;
            else
            Y := Y + 1;
              end if;
          else 
                 X := X + 1;
          end if;
       end if;  
    end if;
```

instead of this

```
 if rising_edge(CLK) then
       if EN = '0' then 
          R <= '0';
            G <= '0';
            B <= '0';
        else 
           R <= toSTD((my_ram(Y)(X)));
            G <= toSTD((my_ram(Y + 204)(X)));
            G <= toSTD((my_ram(Y + 408)(X)));       
        end if;

       if X = 203 then 
           X := 0;
         if Y = 203 then 
            Y := 0;
         else
            Y := Y + 1;
           end if;
        else 
           X := X + 1;
        end if;

    end if;
```

would fix the problem

Comment: The problem isn't readily apparent in your question. The titlei **How to load a text file on a ram in VHDL?**  wherein you added a method for loading the ram yourself.  And ***Okey so this is what i came up with but there's a problem the synthesis is taking forever to finish, so what do you think is the problem here ??!***, where you don't even indicate what the problem is. Are you asking how to get this to synthesize? Which of these questions does your answer address?

Comment: I wanted to know what is the most efficient way to load the contents of a text file into the fpga's memory before i wrote all this code but since you all deemed the question too broad which i don't see that way i went on speaking my mind and trying to get a result out of this and at the end i got the image to be on the screen but with around 5-10 mins of synthesis